# Python KeyboardInterrupt not stopping loop

Tags: python, loops

Python 3.10 in macOS terminal

I kick off this simple script in macOS terminal, which runs infinitely (**so please be warned when running it**):

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.count(start=1):
    try:
        p = pow(2,i)
        print(p)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Loop terminated")
        raise
```

Yet clicking on the keyboard does not terminate the loop.

What am I missing?

Comment: How long does it take for the two lines of code in the `try` loop to run?

Comment: you mean any key or ctrl+c?

Comment: Do you see the text Loop terminated?

Comment: Are you pressing ^C/^Break?

Comment: @defladamouse it runs infinitely.

Comment: @Max I'm not pressing Control-C as my understanding is that `KeyboardInterrupt` is supposed to interrupt the program with any key press.  Is that an incorrect assumption?

Comment: The full loop runs indefinitely, I'm referring to the two lines of code between `try` and `except`, how long do they take to run?  You have to get your `KeyboardInterrupt` to be seen in that time window.

Comment: @defladamouse ah I see, that makes sense.  The `try` block only takes milliseconds to run.  Definitely so fast that I may in fact not be getting the click registered in time.  So how can I adjust my code such that `KeyboardInterrupt` will be recognized globally?  Just wrap the whole code block in a try/except?

Comment: Might work, try it and see.

Comment: I tried it - it does work with Ctrl-C but no other keys.  Does `KeyboardInterrupt` refer strictly to Ctrl-C?

Comment: If *any key press* caused a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, then it would be impossible to ever enter data from the keyboard!

Comment: Yes, only when pressing the "interrupt" key.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html): 
exception KeyboardInterrupt¶
Raised when the user hits the interrupt key (normally Control-C or Delete).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the clarification.  The problem is I was under the assumption that `KeyboardInterrupt` would respond to any key pressed.  It actually only responds to Ctrl-C.  Everything works as expected when using Ctrl-C.